# PDF shows only top row of spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script, pdf

I am attempting to export a spreadsheet which is "created" daily through an automated e-mail in Google Apps Script. When attempting to convert to PDF I only get the top row shown in the PDF document (none of the data).

```
var file = DriveApp.getFileById(spreadsheet.getId()).getAs(MimeType.PDF);

  MailApp.sendEmail('email', 'Equipment Update', 'Spreadsheet Attached', {
name: 'Testing',
attachments: [file]
  });
```

I have checked and the spreadsheet does have the appropriate list of information on the sheet which is to be exported.

Any ideas as to what might be causing this?

Comment: Your advice fixed the issue perfectly, I greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It appears you were trying to convert a spreadsheet to PDF immediately after it was filled with data. This is sometimes an issue because the data may be stuck in a pipeline: the changes are not immediately applied for performance reasons. Use the command

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

before conversion to PDF, to make sure any pending changes are applied. [Reference](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet-app#flush).